# Run time error 1004 method range of object _worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to apply a VLOOKUP function when the data in column D changes. I have applied this exact same code in  workbook Module and it worked perfectly fine. However, when I apply it on a specific worksheet object (set to run when cells experience changes), I get the error stated above. Thank you for the help!

```
Dim ColG_KeyCells As Range
Set ColG_KeyCells = Range("D7:D500")
If Not Application.Intersect(ColG_KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then
    last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 7 To last_row
        referenceNumber = Range("D" & I).Value
        If referenceNumber <> "" Then
            Range("G" & I).Value = 
 Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(referenceNumber,Range("reference_Table"), 4, False)
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Which line errors? This is worksheet change?

Comment: Is your named range spelled exactly the same? `reference_Table` This also seems over engineered, Dim GolG_KeyCells, next line Set it, next line use it then never use it again, why even have as a variable? Also the `_` and continuation doesn't need to happen, just put it on one line and delete the `_`.

Comment: Yes the named range is spelled exactly the same and yes this is Worksheet change. I know because I copied and paste the code (beginning on last_row) from a workbook module and it ran smoothly. Thank you for pointing out the over engineered lines, I will make sure to downsize those.

Comment: If "reference_Table" is a worksheet-scoped name then you need to include the sheet qualifier  - ie `Sheets("someSheet").Range("reference_Table")`

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much for the help. This is my first post so I'm not sure how to flag this as complete.